# iPhone: MKMapView Strange crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I'm having an issue with a `MKMapView`, hope someone can help me.

I have a view that embed a `MKMapView` and a navigationController. I push in my navigationController another viewController then another one again. Then if I go back to the `MKMapView` and touch the map, the application crash.
so MkmapView > View2 > View3 > View2 > MKMapView > touch on the map then crash.

I definitely don't understand why.
If I only push another view then come back, it works well. So:
MkmapView > View2 > MKMapView = OK

I Use the other views in the same way in another part of the application without any problem.
View1 > View2 > View3 > View2 > View1 = OK

I checked, no memory warning `viewDidUnload` or dealloc method are called.

```
The error is: *** -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4806930
```

This time it was an NSURL that crashed but it's almost all the time different: NSArray, NSDictionnary etc...

Here is the stack trace:

```
0    0x3266bdf4 in objc_exception_throw

1    0x32de2bfc in -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]

2    0x32d67b18 in ___forwarding___

3    0x32d5e840 in __forwarding_prep_0___

4    0x32cec074 in -[MKOverlayView _annotationViewForSelectionAtPoint:avoidCurrent:]

5    0x32ce4b60 in -[MKOverlayView annotationViewForPoint:]

6    0x32cc7efc in -[MKMapView _firstTouchBegan:withEvent:]

7    0x32d17e28 in -[MKScrollView _firstTouchBegan:withEvent:]

8    0x32d17c98 in -[MKScrollView touchesBegan:withEvent:]

9    0x30c4a888 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]

10    0x30c49f94 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:]

11    0x30c45790 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]

12    0x30c45094 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent

13    0x31bba990 in PurpleEventCallback

14    0x32da452a in CFRunLoopRunSpecific

15    0x32da3c1e in CFRunLoopRunInMode

16    0x31bb9374 in GSEventRunModal

17    0x30bf3c30 in -[UIApplication _run]

18    0x30bf2230 in UIApplicationMain

19    0x000025f8 in main at main.m:14
```

Does anyone had same kind of issue ? Can someone give me advices on how I could locate the bug or what I should check ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your map view has an annotation.  If you set a breakpoint in your annotation's `-title` method you will get that same stack trace when you touch the map.

Your annotation is getting released prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use MKMapView.delegate=nil before u release the MKMapView object in dealloc method.This is important for iOS 3.0, not imperative in higher versions.

Comment: I have found this to be required in iOS 4.2.

Comment: you saved me dude... worked like a charm after debugging from 2 full days in iOS 5.0 :)

Comment: Please consider Accepting this as the right Answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on zombies.  What's probably happening here is that an NSURL object is being deallocated, and something else is being created at the same address.